# Create dynamic dragpanel in asp.net with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I want to create ajax dragpanel dynamically and add the controls and panel dynamically.I used the below code for create the control dynamically.But I can`t able to drag it.

```
enter code here

protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DragPanelExtender drg = new DragPanelExtender();
    drg.ID = "drg_1";
    drg.DragHandleID = "pnl_1";
    drg.TargetControlID = "pnl_2";
    Panel p1 = new Panel();
    p1.ID = "pnl_1";
    Panel p2 = new Panel();
    p2.ID = "pnl_2";
    Label l1 = new Label();
    l1.Text = "First";
    TextBox t = new TextBox();
    t.Text = "Enter text";
    p2.Controls.Add(l1);
    p2.Controls.Add(t);
    p1.Controls.Add(p2);
    Page.Controls.Add(p1);
}
```

How to I create drag controls inside the panel

Comment: You will need to client script in order to drag the panel around. jQuery is one of the most popular JavaScript frameworks going around and provides well documented functionality to achieve this very task.